# Ошибка сегментации в ассемблере NASM. Архитектура процессора amd64, синтаксис intel (OS - linux)

Tags: ассемблер

```
SECTION .data
msg     db "Hello, world!",0xa  
len     equ $ - msg
SECTION .text
global _start          
_start:
        mov eax, 4     
        mov ebx, 1      
        mov ecx, msg    
        mov edx, len    
        int 0x80        
        mov eax, 1      
        mov ebx, 0      
        int 0x80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `x86_64` помимо того, что указатели стали 64-битными, отличаются [номера системных вызовов](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) и сам способ вызова.

```
SECTION .data
msg     db "Hello, world!",0xa
len     equ $ - msg

SECTION .text
global _start
_start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, len
        syscall
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то я уже не знал  что делать